# How to see stats for 'All Projects' in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

I was looking at http://nemo.sonarqube.org/ and saw that there is a 'Helicopter View' and along with stats for 'All Project'in the system.

See:
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/dashboard/index/219971

I tried to look for this feature in our SonarQube 4.5.2 (community) installation, but was unable to find a way to do it?

- Is this a new feature in SQ 5.0?
- Is this a feature available as a plugin?
- Is this a pay/commercial feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since there isn't anything free out there, I decided to build a simple tool to do what I need to gather the metrics for all projects. For anyone interested, see: https://github.com/charleswhchan/SonarQubeWSUtil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is provided by the [commercial Portfolio Management plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/portfolio-management/) (also called Views).